# How to get JWT token with UID from back-end via Okta service?

Tags: okta

I need to fetch JWT token from back-end which contains UID. How to do it?
I expect an opportunity to do some post request with grant_type: ‘password’. How to set up application which will handle it?

p.s. I know how fetch token via api client (client id and client secret), but it doesn't let to setup proper payload.

Answer (score 0):

If you have username/password for a user you can do resource owner password grant flow to get JWT. But preferred way is to do a redirect to authZ server with authorization code flow, if it's possible

Comment: I tried to do it. I created application with "Application type: - 
"Web". Did post request, and get back - The client is not authorized to use the provided grant type. Configured grant types: [client_credentials, authorization_code, refresh_token, implicit].'

Comment: if you create it as Web application then your login flow should follow it. Resource owner password one does not use /authorize but rather calling /token directly